# What meaning the dash in array when iterating an array in for of loop with entries iterator?

Tags: javascript

If I normally use for of loop and use iterator as entries that situation look like this:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var iterator = a.entries();

for (let e of iterator) {
  console.log(e);
}
// [0, 'a']
// [1, 'b']
// [2, 'c']
```

iterator: will be the entire array that contain all elements key/value pair. Key will be the index.

e: will be an element in the array

**BUT what is this??????**

```
let text = "A A A";
let splitwords = text.split(" ");
let words = [];
for (const [, item] of splitwords.entries()) {
  words.push(item.split(""));
}

console.log(`This is the words: ${words}`);
```

what meaning the **[, item]** part???

and why should i use this pattern?

text.split("") do exactly same thing or not?

(Otherwise I try solve an text animation problem and this inherit from that code:

[framer motion text animation](https://codesandbox.io/s/z7udk?file=/src/AnimatedText.js) )

Thank you

PS: I know this is an array destructing my main question that why????

Comment: The second code snippet doesn't make sense. You can simply iterate over the array. `entries` converts each array element to an array containing the index and the element. `[, item]` discards the index. `entries` is useless in this code.

Comment: I copy and paste two code block. The first from MDN the second framer motion so also senior code. The console.log only for me that see what is going on...

Comment: The second code snippet is nonsense. It won't pass any serious code review. You can replace `for (const [, item] of splitwords.entries()) {` with `for (const item of splitwords) {`

Comment: Thank you. Please check my link that drive you the text animation codesandbox

Comment: _"PS: I know this is an array destructing my main question that why????"_ It's bad code. There is no reason to write such code. It's unnecessary confusing and it's unnecessary longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (const [, item] of splitwords.entries()) {
  words.push(item.split(""));
}
```

`[, item]` is called [array destructing](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment), and the reason for that is because of [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries#iterating_with_index_and_element) in `splitwords.entries()`. The result of that array is like this `[0, "a"],[1, "b"]` (the first item is an index, and the second item is value), but in this case, they don't use an index, so the declaration is like `[,item]` (If they want to use it, the code can be `[index, item]`).

Without using an index, they can implement this way

```
for (const item of splitwords) { //remove entries and array destructing
  words.push(item.split(""));
}
```

> and why should I use this pattern?

Well, I think this is just their code style to use `for of` for collecting both index and value together. It depends on you need an index or not.

`words.push(item.split(""))` is different from the above case, they try to make the entire word `"Hello"` into characters `["H","e","l","l","o"]` for the animation, so the final result of `words` can be

```
[
  ["F","r","a","m","e"],
  ["M","o","t","i","o","n"],
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a destructuring assignment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

`Array.prototype.entries()` returns an array of 2 elements for the index and the item itself for each array item.

So in this expression the index is assign to nothing (because there is no variable declared before the comma) and the item is assigned to `item`.

Example

```js
const ar = [1,2]
const [,value2]=ar
console.log(value2)
const [value1,]=ar
console.log(value1)

const [v1, v2] = ar
console.log(v1, v2)
```

For the `item.split("")` it just seems useless, the result would be the same in the present case with just `words.push(item)` since each word is just one letter... If the words were more than one letter this would just store each letter separately in the `words` array. Which could maybe be called `letters` I guess...

Edit:
for the "why use this pattern" question. In the present case, again it just seems useless. The index is not used so calling `entries` just don't seems relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a way to skip destructuring the first element in the array. You are basically saying that you are not interested in the first array item.
Since the `entries()` method returns a new Array Iterator object that contains the key/value pairs for each index in the array.

```js
const foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (const [, item] of foo.entries()) {
  // item would be 'a', 'b', 'c'
}

for (const [index, item] of foo.entries()) {
  // item would be 'a', 'b', 'c'
  // index would be 0, 1, 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you 'should' use this pattern, but if you want an explanation of what it is, it's like

```
for(let temp of splitwords.entries()){
  const [, item] = temp; 
  words.push(item.split('');
}
```

And then `const [, item] = temp;` is basically the same as `const item = temp[1]`.

Due to how ".entries()" work for an array (giving [index, value]), since the index is ignored by the destructuring, the resulting `item` is just the value. So, I don't think the result is any different from the following:

```
for (const item of splitwords) {
  words.push(item.split(""));
}
```

Maybe they were preparing for the future, in case the index becomes important some day.